# Paypal : By One click Transfer payment from Merchant account to any paypal account using PHP

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-adaptive-payments

**What I want :**

I would like to a paypal transaction like below

From the application once I submit the button  it will deduct amount from Merchant paypal account and deposit to any personal paypal account without any authorization. Is that possible to achieve this ?

**What I have done :**

I have gone through below option of paypal

1. Payment Data Transfer

   https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/paymentdatatransfer/
2. MassPay API Operation (NVP)

   https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/MassPay_API_Operation_NVP/

But Still did not find any perfact way.

Any help will be appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you look into [Adaptive Payments](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/), as PDT is something where you are reliant on PayPal to POST the data back to you. A good candidate for you might be Chained Payments

> A chained payment is a payment from a sender that is indirectly split among multiple receivers. It is an extension of a typical payment from a sender to a receiver, in which a receiver, known as the primary receiver, passes part of the payment to other receivers, who are called secondary receivers.

Comment: But Question is does Paypal allow direct payment from Business to Person without login ?

Comment: MassPay (which you linked) can do this but there is a fee to use it